# WCF como Serviço do Windows

Tags: c#, wcf

Estou criando um WCF, e ele está dessa forma:

```
  ServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Server));
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 999999999;
            ServiceEndpoint point = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServer), binding, url);
            point.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
            host.Open();
```

Em um executável comum, ele funcionava perfeitamente, porém agora preciso dele trabalhando como serviço do Windows, e quando eu incluo ele no projeto de serviço, ele não reconhece o:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
```

E me retorna erro. Como posso proceder ?
Ele não encontra as propriedades, devido não reconhecer a ServiceModel.Web.

Comment: Adicionou a referência à DLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta fazer a referencia , se estiver usando visual Studio , na área do solution explorer tem  as referencias clique com o botão direito do mouse > add reference > assemblies e adicione a system.servicemodel.web